# How to replace the user/contact form in Sulu?

Tags: sulu

I want to know how to change/replace the user/contact form in Sulu i.e. https://sulu.rocks/admin/#/contacts/1/details.

I want to remove the fields for Addresses, Bank accounts, etc.

I tried to copy the `vendor/sulu/sulu/src/Sulu/Bundle/ContactBundle/Resources/config/forms/account_details.xml` into `config/forms` and removed the unnecessary fields. But that not working.

I can't find something to this in the documentation or it's hidden :D

Answer (score 0):

If you add a form with the exact same key as the form you want to override, the contents of both forms are merged. In your case, the key would be `contact_details`. Now you can add completely new properties to the form or override existing ones by just creating a property with the same name. If you want to hide a property, you have to override it and set `visibleCondition="false"`.

You can also have a look at this [example pull request](https://github.com/sulu/sulu-demo/pull/92).